# zegocloud's video/audio sdk flutter package error

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, videocall, zegocloud

### trying to add zego_express_engine in my project.

after adding this package zego_express_engine: ^3.3.1 when i tried to run i got this error,

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':zego_express_engine'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':zego_express_engine:classpath'.
   > Could not download commons-io-2.4.jar (commons-io:commons-io:2.4)
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar'.
            > Read timed out
   > Could not download jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar (org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar'.
         > Read timed out
   > Could not download xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar (xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/xerces/xercesImpl/2.12.0/xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/xerces/xercesImpl/2.12.0/xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar'.
            > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
               > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not download jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar (jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://archiva-maven-storage-prod.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/repository/central/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar?Expires=1681196293&OSSAccessKeyId=LTAIfU51SusnnfCC&Signature=tYD5WoDIl7cLImm5l2lMjhVilAM%3D'.
            > Connect to archiva-maven-storage-prod.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com:443 [archiva-maven-storage-prod.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/121.89.3.239] failed: Read timed out
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':zego_express_engine' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':zego_express_engine' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 19s
```

i want to just add this package in my project that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be due to some network access restrictions, which prevent accessing maven.aliyun.com.

The latest version of express no longer relies on maven.aliyun.com, so there should be no problem anymore.

You can try again with the latest version of express. please refer to https://pub.dev/packages/zego_express_engine.

Answer (score 0):

This error is just because of the slow internet

Comment: ya. That was an internet issue. it's working when I run it with VPN.